# Is this incorrect using of popen(), printf and stdout or bug in glibc?

Tags: c, glibc

I noticed that  my program using function popen
and reassigning stdout fails with printf function

The code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  FILE * tmp = stdout;
  char * command = "cat > newfile.txt";
  double a=12.2344;

  stdout = popen( command, "w"); /* permitted according to glibc tutorial */

  printf("That was laddy\n");  /* This doesn't go to newfile.txt !!!*/

  fprintf(stdout, "And his lass\n"); /* but This goes */


  /* but this...... */
  printf("A double number: %.2f\n", a); /* unexpectedly goes where the
                   first printf hasn't gone */

  /* is it a bug or there is something wrong in a code ? */

  pclose(stdout);

  stdout = tmp;

  return 0;

}
```

What's with function printf? One time it prints on tty but next time 
to file 'newfile.txt' (where it should).
Is it bug with glibc or mistake in code above.
I use that redirection in my utility program.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What does fileno give back when you ask the values of stdout before printf.

Comment: Works for me. No need for `stdout = tmp;` as the process exits.

Comment: I have to ask 'why try it?' It does not seem like a good idea. It is better to design the code to write to a given file stream and then provide the return value from `popen()` to the code. Note that the standard says _The address of the FILE object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a
FILE object need not serve in place of the original._ However, you are not breaching this part of the specification, but some caution is in order. I'm not convinced what you're doing is kosher, but I don't have chapter and verse lined up to counter it. If your code needs to be portable, don't.

Comment: I used eglibc 2.11.3 to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in glibc.  I can reproduce the behavior you describe with libc 2.13 on an x86 Ubuntu with Linux kernel 3.0.0-32-generic.

If I replace the first call to `printf()` with the equivalent `fprintf(stdout,"That was laddy\n");`, all the output goes to the `newfile.txt` file.

Since `printf()` is defined in terms of `fprintf(stdout,...)` there should never be any behavior change when converting a `printf(...)` call to an `fprintf(stdout,...)` call.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the fprintf() and see whether your 1st and 2nd printf() behaves the same way. My guess is that fprintf() is doing something unexpected in the library data structures.

Answer (score 0):

try with a `fflush(stdout)` before popen